# qliksense, how to login with another account than autologin with domain account

Tags: qliksense

I'm using Qlik sense ver 2.1.1, according to the manual of Qlik sense:

> 4.1.1 Users and licenses
>   Before anyone can use Qlik Sense, they must be added to the system and licensed. There are two ways that users are added to Qlik Sense Enterprise.
>
> Local Security Layer—Any user already in the operating system’s security layer (Local User Directory or Active Directory, for example) who tries to connect to Qlik Sense is added to the user directory. Those users are not granted access to any resources until they are licensed, but they appear in the user directory.
>   Directory Sync—After a User Directory Connector (UDC) is configured, users from that directory can be added or synchronized into Qlik Sense. Those users are not granted access to any resources until they are licensed, but they appear in the user directory.

The problem is that I don't want to use domain account to login QLik sense page. I have some pre-defined users on Qlik server for corresponding groups. But, when a new user access Qlik sense page, they're logged in as their domain accounts automatically, and even can't log out, then it's impossible to log-in by my pre-defined user.
How can I change the setting of Qlik sense to disable of this silly automatic log-in mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the default Virtual Proxy created during the Qlik Sense installation always attempts to authenticate people against Windows accounts and it only uses Http Authentication to transmit credentials. (If you want something different, you have to create a different Virtual Proxy.)

If your users don't have a chance to type in credentials, it means the **browser** is configured to automatically supply them when the site asks. You have to turn that setting off. In IE, you can turn it off by going to Internet Options -> Security Tab -> Local Intranet (or whatever makes sense for you) -> Custom Level -> User Authentication (Scroll to the bottom). Set it to the "Prompt for user name and password" setting. Chrome uses IE's settings. In Firefox, go to "about:config", search for "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", and make sure the domain of your Qlik install is **not** in the list.

Unfortunately, with Http Authentication, the **only** way to logout is to close the browser completely (unless there's some browser extension that works around that).

Comment: Thanks, it's a solution. I have also figured out that Qlik have a setting for that in QMC -> Virtual Proxy -> Windows Authentication method, just specify it as  "Form", then a authentication form will be displayed when a user accesses the page.

Comment: Yeah, I just stumbled across that built-in login form yesterday. https://{server}:4244/form   (where 4244 is the configured "Authentication listen port"). For a second, I thought I had a generic login form until I remembered that the service on that port is actually _only_ for Windows Authentication functionality. I wish Qlik Sense would install with the default virtual proxy to use that instead of Http Authentication.